# Permission denied on trying to "rm -rf" my own directory on macOS command line

Tags: permissions, zsh, rm, macos

I have noticed `rm -rf` has a strange behavior in my macOS BigSur.
I created a directory for a font installation:

```bsh
~/code ❯ ls -la                                                         10:06:54
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  21 fredguth  staff   672 Oct 30 08:47 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 71 fredguth  staff  2272 Nov  5 10:07 ..
drwxr-xr-x   7 fredguth  staff   224 Nov  5 09:57 FontPro  <<<<======== This directory
...
```

I am user `fredguth`, the owner of the directory.

```bsh
~/code ❯ whoami                                                  3m 34s 10:21:34
fredguth
```

I am trying to `rm -rf FontPro`.

This happens:

```bsh
rm: FontPro/tfm/MinionPro-MediumItCapt-osf-l1-ly1--lcdfj.tfm: Permission denied
rm: FontPro/tfm/MinionPro-BoldIt-lf-t2a--base.tfm: Permission denied
...
rm: FontPro/dvips/a_fzbwjk.enc: Permission denied
rm: FontPro/dvips: Directory not empty
rm: FontPro: Directory not empty
```

I don't get it. I use `rm -rf` for non-empty directories, and I don't want to use `sudo` if I don't strictly need to.

Is there any macOs setting preventing me from `rm -rf`, or am I missing something else?

Comment: Please add `ls -ld FontPro/tfm` to your question. I think it's likely this directory is missing write permissions

Comment: have you closed the program using usually those subdirs? (on unix it shouldn't matter much, but on mac, there may be a security mechanism preventing removing a file while in use?)

Comment: Have you performed a `chmod -R 755 FontPro` to set correct permissions on all files and directories contained in `FontPro`?

Comment: you can also try:   `find ~/code/FontPro -ls | grep -v "fredguth  staff"` and see if some files belong to some other user. if not, `find -type d ~/code/FontPro -ls | grep -v "^..w."` will find those subdirs where you don't have, as the user, writing right (necessary to delete subdirs and files within that dir).  And welcome to unix.se !

Comment: @roaima What a newbie mistake!

Comment: @JG7 you are right.  My bad. Jeez.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newbie mistake. On comments suggestion:

```bsh
~/code ❯ ls -ld FontPro/tfm
drwxr-xr-x  8156 root  staff  260992 Oct 26 21:26 FontPro/tfm
```

I just realized that there is this subdir that is owned by root.
This is the culprit.

```bsh
~/code ❯ sudo chown -R fredguth FontPro                             33s 10:33:20
~/code ❯ ls -ld FontPro/tfm                                             10:33:39
drwxr-xr-x  8156 fredguth  staff  260992 Oct 26 21:26 FontPro/tfm
~/code ❯ rm -rf FontPro                                                 10:33:44
~/code ❯
```

### working now.

P.S. @JG7 and @roaima, if you post an answer I can mark yours as the right one.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar situation, but the folder was owned by me. Turns out I had a Docker for Mac container running that was using the folder as a bind mount. Stopping my containers allowed me to delete the folder.

```bsh
> rm -rf The.Folder.In.Question/
rm: The.Folder.In.Question/: Permission denied
> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                     NAMES
26072a9ee2d7   logtestmicroservice             "dotnet watch"           12 minutes ago   Up 12 minutes   0.0.0.0:55008->8080/tcp   LogTestMicroService_container
bcf515e5792e   logtestmicroservice_generator   "dotnet watch -- run…"   13 minutes ago   Up 13 minutes   0.0.0.0:55007->8080/tcp   LogTestMicroService_generator_container
> docker stop 26072a9ee2d7 bcf515e5792e
26072a9ee2d7
bcf515e5792e
> rm -rf The.Folder.In.Question/ && echo good
good
```

Comment: This was not the root cause and should be considered an edge case, especially since not everyone runs Docker, but it is still a decent answer for someone who finds themselves in your particular situation.